# Updating SVD $A=U*S*U^{T}$ after shifting diagonal elements of A

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a matrix $Y$ with `m` rows and `n` columns (m>n)

I create a symmetric square matrix $A$ as

$A = Y^{T} * Y$

and then compute a jacobian SVD of it such that

$A = U * S * U^{T}$

now I have to add a value $x$ to the diagonal elements of $A$

$B = A + x * I$

I should now compute an SVD again of B. Can I do that by altering $U$ and/or $S$ somehow instead of computing an SVD again?

Answer (score 1):

If $A = Y^{\top} Y$, then $A$ is symmetric and therefore your SVD is an eigenvalue decomposition $A = V \Lambda V^{\top}$ with $VV^{\top} = V^{\top} V = I$ and $\Lambda$ a diagonal matrix. Therefore, you can factor

$$
B = A + x I = V \Lambda V^{\top} + x I = V \Lambda V^{\top} + x VV^{\top} =
V (\Lambda + xI) V^{\top},
$$
which means that the eigenvalues of $B$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ plus the added constant $x$, and its eigenvectors stay the same as previously.